# Tensorflow GPU installation problems

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, python-2.7

I have tried to install tensor flow in my system and i am incurring following error

```
" Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/vasudev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/basecommand.py", line 215, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "/home/vasudev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/commands/install.py", line 342, in run
    prefix=options.prefix_path,
  File "/home/vasudev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_set.py", line 778, in install
    requirement.uninstall(auto_confirm=True)
  File "/home/vasudev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_install.py", line 754, in uninstall
    paths_to_remove.remove(auto_confirm)
  File "/home/vasudev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/req/req_uninstall.py", line 115, in remove
    renames(path, new_path)
  File "/home/vasudev/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pip/utils/__init__.py", line 267, in renames
    shutil.move(old, new)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 300, in move
    rmtree(src)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 252, in rmtree
    onerror(os.remove, fullname, sys.exc_info())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 250, in rmtree
    os.remove(fullname)
OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/funcsigs/__init__.pyc' "
```

I have changed the permissions of my Python 2.7 folder , but still I'm getting same error during installation.

Kindly please inform me on the problem in my installation procedure.

Comment: Are you using 'sudo' if required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you can see detailed/official instructions how to install tensorflow on Ubuntu: https://www.tensorflow.org/get_started/os_setup

As mentioned by grooveplex - the source of the bellow error seems to be lack of write permissions. The use of `sudo` should solve the problem.

> OSError: [Errno 13] Permission denied